# Android screenshot app - null pointer exception

Tags: android, screenshot

I am trying to test code to take screenshot on the android emulator. I have the following code to start with:

```
    View content = ((ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
    content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(content.getDrawingCache());
    content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

But I get null pointer exception in createBitmap at line 551.

Can someone please point out what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem could come from your View content :

```
View content = ((ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
```

Did you try remove `getChildAt(0)` or to replace it by `getRootView()` ?

Else, there is a good website with a sample there if it can help you (last post on the first forum page):
 [Capture Screen With Coding](http://www.anddev.org/how_to_capture_screen_with_coding-t3755.html)

Tell me if you find how to solve it.

Comment: I used the code : Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache(), and I did not get the null pointer exception. As the emulator has root privilege, if I ran this code on a phone, would I get an exception ? Also, why does the app not require READ_FRAME_BUFFER permission ? Thanks

Comment: On running on the emulator, I get bitmap = null.

Answer (score 0):

You must use MeasureSpec in some cases. Try this:

```
View content = ((ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.content));
content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
content.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
content.layout(0, 0, content.getMeasuredWidth(), content.getMeasuredHeight());
content.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(content.getDrawingCache());
```